# On server shut down AtomicBoolean chinging too late (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, atomic

I'm working on a Client-Server application and I want to shut down the server when a stop message is received over the socket.The code for my Server looks like this

```
public class Server extends Thread {

 private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);


  public synchronized void setRunning(boolean value){
        running.set(value);
    }

 public void run(){

        while(running.get()){
                try {
                     clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                     //doing stuff...

                }catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("{} \n",e.getMessage());
                }
        }
```

The variable running is set in another class that handles my messages. The function is written like this

```
public synchronized void onReceive(Message message){

       if(message.equals(stopMessage)){

           server.setRunning(false);
           for(Client c : clients)
               c.shutdown();
           server.shutdown();
       }
}
```

My problem is that the while loop in server executes one more iteration before setting the running variable to false and the server tries to check the socket even thought it is null since the client connected to that socket is already closed (the client is also a thread).I do something wrong but I don't know what. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Why is `setRunning()` synchronized? It does not do anything else than setting an `Atomic…` …

Comment: At the first attempt I used a boolean. Then I changed to AtomicBoolean. I tried without synchronized but the result it's the same

Comment: `accept()` blocks. Your loop won't get to examine the Boolean until the next connection has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `while` loop like this:

```
while( running.get() )
{
    try( clientSocket = serverSocket.accept() ) 
    {
        if( !running.get() ) break;
        //doing stuff...

    }
    catch( SocketTimeoutException e )
    {
        continue;
    }
    catch( SocketException e )
    {
        if( !serverSocket.isClosed() ) logger.error( "{} \n", e.getMessage() );
        break;
    }
    catch( IOException e ) 
    {
        logger.error( "{} \n", e.getMessage() );
        break;
    }
}
```

The loop is waiting in `serverSocket.accept()` and will proceed only on an incoming connection or on a timeout. Changing `running` does not wake it up, so it recognises that change only on the next cycle in the `while` loop.

And after an error exception, you should not continue the loop. Even in case of a `SocketTimeoutException`, `continue` might not be correct/sufficient.

Comment: I understand what you are saying since the accept() function is blocking but the change in the loop with the condition and break didn't solve it, it's wierd it should break the loop.

Comment: That break can't solve it because the function accept() is iterrupted so the execution goes directly in the catch so nothing after the accept() function will be executed so it never reaches the if after it. Using getAcquire() it's the same.

Comment: In that case, your problem is by no means a problem with the `running` flag … although you can check it in the `catch` clause again and if false, take the exception as expected and do not log it. But that is a dirty hack …

Comment: I've been thinking to verify in the catch but it is not the best idea. I will try with the InterruptedException. Thank you!

Comment: There is a socket leak here. The accepted socket must be closed if it isn't going to be handled. `Socket.accept()` isn't interruptible.

Comment: I close the socket by calling server.shutdown(). It's the only way to interrupt it I guess